# maven custom plugin not working after download from central repo

Tags: java, maven

I've created custom plugin (http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=sk/lukasvasek/project-version-dategenerator-mvn/0.0.001/project-version-dategenerator-mvn-0.0.001.pom). When I install it locally (mvn install) i can use goal dateversionoverrider withou problem. Hovewer when I download this plugin from maven central repo I'm getting error:

[ERROR] Could not find goal 'dateversionoverrider' in plugin sk.lukasvasek:project-version-dategenerator-mvn:0.0.001 among available goals

what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ok so problem was in descriptor, so I changed it to code below and it works.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <goalPrefix>project-version-dategenerator</goalPrefix>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>help-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```